# Using TempData and deleting it in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, model-view-controller

I have to use TempData from one controller to another one. But on the last controller's view, I am using a jQuery script to check the value of the TempData and if the value corresponds to what I need to do, a popup shows up.

After the popup, I want to delete the value of my temp data. 
I have used `@(TempData["myKey"]).Remove` and `TempData.Remove("mykey")` in the script, but still no luck.

I know there are alternatives(viewbag, viewdata,s ession) but I have to use TempData since the user will be redirected.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: TempData only exists for the space of one read.  When you check the value of the entry, it's automatically deleted.  In fact, this is one reason why you shouldn't use tempdata for inter-controller communication.  What happens if the user presses F5?  The value is now gone from the first read and your app may be in an unpredictable state.  It's fine if this is just a notification message that you don't care if it's not there when the user refreshes the page, but should not be used if this value is necessary for the operation of the page.

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusch, The value of TempData deleted or removed only if you read its value. If you only check, value is still present until you read it. In my case it's a value check, not a value reading.

Comment: One your view is displayed, your no longer connected to the server!

Comment: @StephenMuecke, I did not quite understand what you mean.

Comment: How do you think that you can remove something that exists on the server without contacting the server (e.g. using ajax). But using `TempData` is not the correct approach and you have not given enough information to understand what your really trying to so.